# Using OAuth 2 on a mobile divice without a redirect URI to a web server

Tags: objective-c, ios5, redirect, uri, oauth-2.0

I am working on developing my app using a company's web service API.

When registering for the API key, the company require me to submit a redirect URI.

It is easy to display a web page in my IOS app and send the user to authorization server and let them grant me the access, but I cannot figure out how to obtain an URI of my own Iphone + the port of my app  so the authorization server can send back access token to my application.

Is there a different way to deal with OAuth 2.0 in mobile application without setting a web server and use its URI as a redirect URI ?

I could not find any related issue on Stack Overflow.  Please send me some links if there exist a solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: This link is a great solution to this problem ( it is also compatible with IOS 5.1 and XCode 4.3 )

The example app use Google GTM OAuth2 also solve the problem of wiring the xib of this library to the main story board.

https://singly.com/getting_started_ios

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to [register a custom URI scheme](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) for your app and then set your custom URI as redirect URI. Your browser then gets redirected there and ios calls your app.

There are also other methods e.g. at [Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi), but most of them have to be supported by your provider.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the great response.  Do you know the listener method that can intercept the part when the browser gets redirected?

Comment: Checkout [this tutorial](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html) or the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50). Since iOS 4.2 it's `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`.

Answer (score 1):

This link is a great solution to this problem ( it is also compatible with IOS 5.1 and XCode 4.3 )

The example app use Google GTM OAuth2 also solve the problem of wiring the xib of this library to

https://singly.com/getting_started_ios